# Google Maps Markers not appearing in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am very green when it comes to coding and PhoneGap so please bear with me.

I am trying to have my Custom Google Map load in my PhoneGap application. The map loads but the markers do not. I can see that the app is getting my current location as well as connecting to the internet. My app gets the markers from an online database.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="-----" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"     xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
<name>---</name>
<description>
   --app.
</description>
<author email="---" href="----">
   ---
</author>

<preference name="permissions" value="none" />
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.6.3" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
<preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
<preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
<preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
<preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
<preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
<preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon3.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="mdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="hdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="xhdpi" src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="57" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="72" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="114" src="res/icon/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" />
<icon gap:platform="ios" height="144" src="res/icon/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="480" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="960" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1136" src="res/screen/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-568h-2x.png" width="640" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="1024" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="ios" height="768" src="res/screen/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" />
<gap:splash gap:platform="winphone" src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.jpg" />
<access origin="*" />
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<access origin="*" />
<access origin="*.google.com" />
<access origin="*.mywebsite.com" subdomains="true" />
<access origin="www.mywebsite.com/m/get_locations.php" />
<access origin="*.googleapis.com" />
<access origin="*.gstatic.com" />
<access origin="*.googleusercontent.com" />
<access origin="google.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="googleapis.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="gstatic.com" subdomains="true"/>
<access origin="googleusercontent.com" subdomains="true"/>

</widget>
```

Here is the main code for the map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/contact_me.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>








  <meta charset="utf-8">



<title>----</title>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-----&libraries=places"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



function makeRequest(url, callback) {

    var request;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    } else {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
    }
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            callback(request);
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.send();
}


// This example adds a search box to a map, using the Google Place Autocomplete
// feature. People can enter geographical searches. The search box will return a
// pick list containing a mix of places and predicted search terms.

function initialize() {
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 
  var initialLocation;


  var markers = [];
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

  });

  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(-37.926032, 145.098479),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-38.229056, 145.779930));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);


  var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true};


  if(navigator.geolocation) {
  var options = {enableHighAccuracy: true};
    browserSupportFlag = true;
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position, options) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
      map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
  }
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
  else {
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
  }

  function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
      alert("Geolocation service failed, Please enable Geolocation on your browser or device.");
      initialLocation = defaultBounds;
    } else {
      alert("Please enable Geolocation on your browser or device");
      initialLocation = defaultBounds;
    }
    map.setCenter(initialLocation);
  }



//Put location here

 function displayLocation(location) {
 var geocoder= new google.maps.Geocoder();


    var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'  + location.name + '</strong>'
                    + '<br/>'     + location.address  + '<br/>' +  '<a href="tel:' + location.phone +' " target="_blank"  > '+ location.phone +' </a>'    
                    + '<br/>' +  '<a href="' + location.web +' " target="_blank"  > '+ location.web +' </a>' + '<br/>'    + location.type + '</div>';

    if (parseInt(location.lat) == 0) {
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': location.address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var iconBase = '/img/marker.png';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                    icon: iconBase,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: location.name
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(content);
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(location.lat), parseFloat(location.lon));

        var iconBase = '/img/marker.png';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            icon: iconBase,
            map: map, 
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            position: position,
            title: location.name
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(content);
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    }
} //Ends display location

 makeRequest('get_locations.php', function(data) {

        var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            displayLocation(data[i]);
        }
    });

     // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(
    /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(input));



  // [START region_getplaces]
  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects an item from the
  // pick list. Retrieve the matching places for that item.
  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();


      if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);

    }


    var content =   '<div class="infoWindow"><strong>'  + location.name + '</strong>'
                    + '<br/>'     + location.address
                    + '<br/>'     + location.type + '</div>';

    // For each place, get the icon, place name, and location.
    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: '/img/marker.png',
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };
    // Create a marker for each place.
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
            }); 

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);


    map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }




  }); //Ends add listener



  // Bias the SearchBox results towards places that are within the bounds of the
  // current map's viewport.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });

} //Ends init





google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

 </script>

       </head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="fix">  
<div data-role="header" class="header">
            Search for pet accommodation in Australia!
            <a data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" href="index.html" rel="external"></a>

        </div>


<div id="home">
    <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        <br><br>


<div id="scroll">
        <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" bgcolor="#2ecc71" font-family= "Comic Sans MS" width="100%"><img src="img/paws1.gif" alt="paws" width="40" height="20"/>  Please do not leave your pets unattended on a lead/leash <img src="img/paws1.gif" alt="paws" width="40" height="20"/> Gold Coast Spots - training for you and your dog, puppies to golden oldies! Call Sharon at 0410159026 mention Cruisin' pets for 5% discount!<img src="img/paws1.gif" alt="paws" width="40" height="20"/> </marquee>
   </div> 



</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. The code works on my laptop and on the mobile version. The app seems to be the only problem.

Comment: can you provide code by which you are trying to display maps and its marker. you need to refresh maps once you add marker.

Comment: @DeepMehta i just added the code for you, the markers are suppose to load once the map loads. So for instance someone loads the map they see all the markers on the map once the map loads.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out and try to open in your phonegap app. Save it as .html file and open this page in your app.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&signed_in=true"></script>
    <script>
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.

function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatlng
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
      '<div id="siteNotice">'+
      '</div>'+
      '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">text</h1>'+
      '<div id="bodyContent">'+
      '<p><b>Some text</b>, text' +

      '.</p>'+
      '</div>'+
      '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'text'
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That code worked, the marker showed but when i try and use my markers from the info in my database that is stored online they do not show up. I am not sure as to why exactly. I dont know if it is because of my config.xml file or if it is because of the app not being able to actually talk to the online database and pull the information from it.

Comment: Try creating static array of your response which you get from database and try to implement that first. I think it's getting some error when u update your markers. Also check console logs.

Comment: This is what I get when I try to load the file in my browser.............   XMLHttpRequest cannot load ------/www/get_locations.php. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.makeRequest @ search.php:177
search.php:177 Uncaught NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load '----/www/get_locations.php'.
main.js:31 Uncaught InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Comment: You have problem in lat long you are passing. Make sure they are Google.maps.latlng()

Comment: I believe that error is only happening in my browser because I use the geolocation from gps to get the lat and lon for the app so since the computer doesn't have that it cant get the correct information, correct? When i load the file on the phone it gets the lat and lon and I can see that because it finds my location then sets the lat and lon bounds to my location.

Comment: Yea pass static latlong and see if u can read data from your server and get markers on browser or not.